# Difference between obj.func(arg) and obj.func.bind(obj, arg)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just came across a the following structure in a piece of React code (names changed):

```
<MyActionComponent callback={this.func.bind(this, arg)}>
```

From what I understand, `bind` simply executes the corresponding function with the function's `this` set to the first argument and passing further arguments to it.
Since `func` is already a property of the object we want to be `this`, it seems that `this.func(arg)` would result in the same behaviour.

I fail to see the motivation behind what seems like a more complex syntax for identical functionality.
Is there any context where `obj.func(arg)` would behave differently compared to `obj.func.bind(obj, arg)`? Or are there non-technical aspects (e.g. convention, consistency) I'm unaware of?

Comment: Your callback uses this inside it and callback usually gets called with the context of window, but here we are making sure that it gets called with the context of MyActionComponent

Comment: @SharathBangera: If `this` is window, we would still be calling it in the context of window using either code above.

Comment: you're calling the function on first load. when it suppose to run on an event to be triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical difference is that `obj.func(arg)` *executes* the function whereas `func.bind(obj, arg)` does *not execute* the function. It only ensures that `this` will be bound to `obj` once the function get's actually executed.

See here:

```
var obj = {
  fooFn: function() {console.log("this = ", this)}
}

obj.fooFn() // => prints "this = [Object]"

var boundFn = obj.fooFn.bind("bar")
boundFn() // => prints "this = 'bar'"
```

Comment: Ah yeah, it just creates a "derivate" of said function with bound context and possibly arguments. Idk how I could miss this... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to setting the `this` context, [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) also allows you to 
set arguments that are prepended to the arguments when the function is called. The return value of `bind`ing a function is not the result of calling the function, rather a function that can be called with a bound `this` context and prepended arguments that are specified when the function was bound.

```js
const addStuff = function(a, b) {
  this.sum += a;
  this.sum += b;
};

const resultA = { sum: 0 };
const add_A_and_B = addStuff.bind(resultA);
add_A_and_B(1, 2);

console.log("add_A_and_B(1, 2):", resultA);

const resultB = { sum: 0 };
const add_5_and_B = addStuff.bind(resultB, 5);
add_5_and_B(2);

console.log("add_5_and_B(2):", resultB);
```

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed that it returns a function rather than exectuing it and returning the results. Now the callback makes more sense too, as it's an actual function.